# How to interpret arg min in the the following equation?

Tags: signal-analysis, statistics, optimization

I am studying the following equation:

$$\hat{s}_m(n) = \arg \min_{s_m(n)\in A_s}\left| \frac{\psi_m^H}{||\psi_m^H||^2}y_m(n)-s_m(n)\right|^2\tag{1}$$

here $A_s$ is 1x$N$ vector of QPSK symbols, $s_m(n)$ belongs to $A_s$, $\psi_m$ is a random complex number, $y_m(n)$ is 1x$N$ vector and $n$ ranges from $1$ to $N$ and **I have all these values.**

My query is what does arg min is signifying in this equation (1).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\arg\min$ is the argument of the minimum, in this case it is the value for $s_m(n)$ for each index $n$ that would minimize $|\frac{\psi_m^H}{||\psi_m^H||^2}y_m(n)-s_m(n)|^2$.  This will result in the set of values $\hat{s}_m(n)$ that results in the minimum distance; in this case the closest QPSK symbol for each of the samples $y(n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer ....will try to implement it in MATLAB now...

Comment: Sir, from your answer I had understood the following: "If $N$ is 8 then $y_m(n)$ and $s_m(n)$ both will be 1x8 vector. Thus the term inside square of absolute in eq.(1) will also be 1x8 vector. " Is my understanding mentioned in double quote correct? Also, I am not getting how to proceed after this step....

Comment: Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated...

Comment: @chaaru The term inside the absolute value brackets are scalars. $N$ is 8 but $n$ is an index over each of those 8 values in the vector. $y_m$ is 1x8 but $y_m(n)$ is a single value depending on what $n$ is.  The idea is to index through each value and then for each one determine the closest QPSK symbol, once you normalize the entire values. Since there are only 8 values, can you update your question to include the values and show your steps up to where you are stuck?

Comment: $\frac{\psi^H}{||\psi^H||^2} = -0.06 - 1.16i$, $y_m(n) = [-0.41+ 0.41i 0.54 - 0.58i -0.62- 0.71i 0.64+ 0.56i -0.70 + 0.75i 0.68 - 0.60i -0.54- 0.55i 0.43 + 0.79i]$, $s_m(n) = [0.70 + 0.70i -0.70 - 0.70i -0.70 + 0.707 0.70 - 0.70i 0.70 + 0.70i -0.70 - 0.70i -0.70 + 0.70i 0.70 - 0.70i]$.  Since we have to find  the closest elements in $s_m(n)$ to each of the members of $\frac{\psi^H}{||\psi^H||^2}y_m(n)$, I write in MATLAB as: [~,minind_min] = min(abs((sn' - part1).^2),[],2); s_mn_hat_min = part1(minind_min); where sn = $s_m(n)$, part1 is the $\frac{\psi^H}{||\psi^H||^2}y_m(n)$.

Comment: @chaaru Does it all make sense now to you?

Comment: Yes sir.....I want to confirm whether its correct or not....

Comment: Sir, can u please confirm whether my MATLAB code statement correct or not...

Comment: I can't really be sure looking at the code as I would need to check each result to see that it did return the minimum distance solution. What I recommend that you do, since it is only 10 samples, is go through each one and confirm the result is closest to the QPSK symbol selected. If it is, then your code is working.